# programmatically lock GitLab branch

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

**Background:**
We'd like to lock branch for merging while deploy Jenkins job is running

**Question:** 
Is there way to programmatically lock GitLab branch?

*e.g. To set "maintainers_can_push": false" on GitLab protected branch*

**Checked so far:**

1. Haven't found any mention of such functionality at [GitLab](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin)
   plugin.
2. Haven't found anything on [GitLab branches API page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html)

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html

Comment: @phd Thanks! Plz feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#protect-repository-branch there is a link to the page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html devoted to API calls for listing protected branches, protect and unprotect them.

To protect a branch call `POST /projects/:id/protected_branches`. For example

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/protected_branches?name=*-stable&push_access_level=30&merge_access_level=30&unprotect_access_level=40'
```

Comment: For further investigation, please, put at least some summary of solution directly to SO, many thanks.

Comment: Would this also lock/prevent merges from within the Merge Request UI? That is what we're looking for

Comment: No. Branch protection is about forbidding pushing. Merge requests are allowed anyway. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html